# Detect whether multiple ListView items were selected by dragging

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView with the View set to LargeIcon.
I specifically need to detect when multiple items were selected by dragging a selection box around them with the mouse.
(For example I don't want to know when items were selected by CTRL + Click)

I thought I could simply do it by keeping track of whether the mouse was down while it was moving which would indicate dragging, then on mouse up if it was a drag then I can set another variable to indicate this.

In my example below `mouseDown` is set to true, but when I keep the mouse down and move it `isDrag` is never set to true and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
(Edit: `isDrag` becomes true if I remove the `if` clause which is weird because as I said `mouseDown` is definitely true).

I realise the code is a little longer than it needs to be but it's for clarity.

```
bool mouseDown;
bool isDrag;
bool wasDrag;

private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    wasDrag = false;
    mouseDown = true;
}

private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    if (mouseDown)
        isDrag = true; // <-- Never becomes true, even though mouseDown is true
}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    if (isDrag)
        wasDrag = true;

    mouseDown = false;
    isDrag = false;
}
```

I know it'll be something stupid. Please put me out of my misery.
Alternatively if someone knows of a better was to detect a dragging selection (what's the proper term?) then I'm all ears.

Comment: In your mouseup, get the ListView1.SelectedItems property. Any items selected during the drag should be available in this property once the mouse is released.

Comment: That would include items selected by clicking while holding control. I want items specifically selected by dragging.

Comment: May sound like a stupid question, but I have to ask it anyway: Are you sure that the `listView1_MouseMove` method is actually assigned to the `listview1`'s `MouseMove` event handler? Just have a look in the `InitializeComponent()` method

Comment: It is definitely assigned, a breakpoint set inside that handler is triggered. Alex, I've updated my question to be clearer, thanks!

Comment: Can you hook `listView1_PreviewMouseDown` and  `listView1_PreviewMouseMove`? It might simply be that the event is being handled before it has bubbled far enough for MouseDown and MouseMove to respond. Your approach seems to be sound, so long as you can hook the events early enough.

Comment: I can't see that event. This is Winforms, not WPF.

Comment: OK, after some investigation I think I made a mistake with my breakpoints and have diagnosed what's wrong, I just don't know what to do about it. Basically the MouseMove event doesn't fire so long as MouseDown is still going on. As soon as MouseDown is finished both MouseMove and MouseUp fire immediately. I think I shall ask a separate question about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I've discovered that for a ListView control the MouseMove event will not fire while MouseDown is still occurring and fires immediately after releasing the mouse.
I can only assume that the logic built into this control that allows you to select multiple files by dragging a selection is messing with these events and essentially making them synchronous.

I've put together a basic workaround for this. It's not ideal but it does the job so I thought I'd share.

Basically when the mouse goes down I record the position. When the mouse goes up I check to see if it has moved more than a certain distance in any direction. If it has not I consider it a click, if it has I consider it a drag.

```
// Records the mouse position on mousedown
int beforeMoveX;
int beforeMoveY;

// How far in pixels the mouse must move in any direction
// before we consider this a drag rather than a click
int moveBounds = 20;

private void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Save the mouse position
    beforeMoveX = e.X;
    beforeMoveY= e.Y;
}

private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Did we move more than the bounds in any direction?
    if (e.X < (beforeMoveX - moveBounds) || 
        e.X > (beforeMoveX + moveBounds) || 
        e.Y < (beforeMoveY - moveBounds) || 
        e.Y > (beforeMoveY + moveBounds))
    {
        // DRAGGED!
    }
    else
    {
        // NOT DRAGGED!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    isDrag = mouseDown;
}
```

I think for some reason, your event **listView1_MouseUp** still fires, which makes your isDrag variable set to other than the intended value. Try to put breakpoints on both **MouseMove** and **MouseUp** events to see the sequence with which they are firing.

Comment: Although I had tried both of these things and they unfortunately didn't work you did jog my brain and lead me to solve it so have an upvote my friend.